An indefinite integral within a definite integral and a confusion regarding positioning the variable.
So I have an integral to solve for (this comes out as the second term of integration by parts), which is supposed to give me a function of $a$.
The integral is as follows:
$\int_{\infty}^{a} 2 u\left (  \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}\frac{dln(n)}{du}du\right )du$
Can I just take the $\frac{dln(n)}{du}$ out of the inner indefinite integral and insert the $2u$ in it's place instead?, if yes, why can I do that? I want to understand. So that the whole integral becomes:
$\int_{\infty}^{a} \left (  \int \frac{2 u}{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}du\right )\frac{dln(n)}{du}du$
Here, $n$ is a function of $u$, and $a$ is a parameter.
